# iOS Coremotion accelerator updates in background/ sleepmode

Tags: ios, objective-c, accelerometer, core-motion

I need accelerator updates when the app is running in background/ the device is in sleep mode. Some apps do this, I could not make it working.
For this I have a CoreMotion property in my appdelegate and in applicationDidEnterBackground I call

```
-(void) startAccelerationUpdates
{

    self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01;
    [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                       withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error){
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         NSLog(@"acceleration x %f", motion.userAcceleration.x);
         NSLog(@"acceleration y %f", motion.userAcceleration.y);
         NSLog(@"acceleration z %f", motion.userAcceleration.z);
         }
         );
         }
    ];
}
```

In the app plist I put Required background modes to App registers for location updates. When I put the device in sleep mode or in background no updates appear in the logs. When the app gets active coremotion starts loggin. Anyone got a hint for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you dispatch it to main queue. To enable background activity, you should dispatch it to global queue :

```
dispatch_queue_t lowQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0);
dispatch_async(lowQueue, ^{ ...
```

---

**UPDATE** Add Swift version:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)) {
    // do some task
}
```

Reference: [using the same dispatch queue in a method for background processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275180/using-the-same-dispatch-queue-in-a-method-for-background-processing)

Comment: Thank you, but with dispatch to global queue it is not working either.

Comment: Additionally, in your App's plist, did you use `Required background modes`-> and at `item 0` choose `App registers for location updates`?

Comment: Yes I did. Location updates are working in background/sleep mode.

Comment: @simon how are you determining that the samples don't get recorded? Don't trust NSLog or anything similar in this case - try recording the timestamp of each sample and you'll see it's continuous.

Comment: Is it also possible by your solution to detect in background if user is in automotive/running/walking?

Comment: yes, but in addition, you have to indicate you have background activity in your App property list. Read more at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989278/ios-7-long-running-background-task

Comment: Great thanks very much, is it also possible, with that technique to start gps or other services if e.g. walking to running? Thanks in advance

Comment: What would it look like in swift?