# iOS 7 - Long running background task

Tags: ios, ios7, xamarin

Similar to [iOS long-running background timer with "location" background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15650139/462935) but not exactly.

Our app needs to send occasional geolocation data in the background. Works fine in foreground but it, of course, gets terminated after 3 minutes. So I need to implement something like this. Has anyone done this in C# and, if so, would you be willing to share?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18962839/462935

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can only have your app wake up on significant location changes. Please see [CLLocationManager while app is in background state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691814/cllocationmanager-while-app-is-in-background-state).

You cannot simply run your app in the background indefinitely, which is part of iOS's design for minimal power usage. It would be good to read Apple's documentation on [App State and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).

Comment: Thanks!  I've rewritten it using Significant Changes, and it seems to be working.