# Long GPS background updates

Tags: ios, gps

My application is GPS-aware and registered to get GPS updates while in the background.

What will happen if in the GPS updates event handler I have a time-consuming task, will my application be killed?

Comment: Good answer to your question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989278/ios-7-long-running-background-task

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered many times before, I believe. Short answer: yes. A slightly longer answer is that Apple does not clearly document how and when this will happen, but [documents a guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) to keep the background processing short.

To quote:

> Save your app state before moving to the background. During low-memory
>   conditions, background apps may be purged from memory to free up
>   space. **Suspended apps are purged first, and no notice is given to the
>   app before it is purged**.
>
> [...]
>
> **The execution time given to background apps
>   is more constrained than the amount of time given to the foreground
>   app**. Apps that spend too much time executing in the background can be
>   throttled back by the system **or terminated**.

I can add that I myself did some experimentation around this back in the iOS5 days, and you did not have a lot of background processing time (not nearly as long as the 10 minutes you have for registered background tasks).